# Trying to save an order that contains a list of products

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm building an E-commerce API, but now i'm facing a problem that i can't save the list of products that my order must contain.

I don't know if its the relation that i'm using between the entities or something else, but here they are:

Order

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "cpf")
private Client client;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
private List<OrderProduct> products = new ArrayList<>();

@Column(name = "total")
private double total;

@Column(name = "status")
private StatusEnum status;

@Column(name = "createdAt")
private LocalDate createdAt;

public Order() {}
}
```

OrderProduct

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_products")
public class OrderProduct implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private Order order;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private Product product;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

public OrderProduct(Order order, Product product, Integer quantity) {
    this.order = order;
    this.product = product;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public double getTotalPrice() {
    return this.product.getPrice() * this.quantity;
 }
}
```

And here's the service method to create the order

```
public Order create(OrderDTO orderObj) {
    Client orderClient = clientService.get(orderObj.getClient());
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setCreatedAt(LocalDate.now());
    order.setProducts(this.getOrderProducts(order, orderObj.getProducts()));
    order.setClient(orderClient);
    order.setTotal(this.getOrderTotal(order));
    order.setStatus(StatusEnum.PROCESSING);

    return orderRepository.save(order);
}

private List<OrderProduct> getOrderProducts(Order order, Map<Long, Integer> productsObj) {
    List<OrderProduct> products = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entry : productsObj.entrySet()) {
        Product product = productService.updateProductStock(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), true);
        products.add(new OrderProduct(order, product, entry.getValue()));
    }
    return products;
}
```

I've tried the solution above, but i'm getting the following error:

```
2024-03-28T21:34:59.872-03:00 ERROR 23600 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.prependPath(JsonMappingException.java:455) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:790) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track for building out the relations between your entities. However, one important thing to understand is that in a bidirectional relationship, you need to consider both sides.

When an `Order` is saved, it doesn't automatically save the `OrderProduct`s associated with it. This is related to the `CascadeType` in JPA. If you want to save the `Order` and the `OrderProducts` at the same time, you should do something like:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<OrderProduct> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here, `CascadeType.ALL` means that all operations (Persist, Merge, Refresh, Remove and Detach) that are performed on the `Order` will also be performed on the `OrderProduct`.

However, a simple addition of cascade type might not be enough in this case. The problem arises because of how Hibernate manages the entity state. When a new `OrderProduct` is added to the `Order`, Hibernate does not know about it because the `Order` is in a detached state while you add new `OrderProducts` to it (in `getOrderProducts()` method).

To handle this, we need to make sure that both sides of the relation are updated properly. This would generally involve the following step:

- In your `OrderProduct` entity, add `order.addProduct(this);` at the end of the constructor.

And in the `Order` entity:

```java
public void addProduct(OrderProduct product){
    products.add(product);
    product.setOrder(this);
}
```

In this way, the relationship is managed both ways and Hibernate will be aware of the relationship and proceed to act on `cascade` settings.

Comment: Thanks in advance mate, i've tried the solution that you said but now im getting a StackOverFlowError, gonna edit the post for you to see.

Comment: The order got saved with everything ok, but i still got this error that i putted above in the post

Comment: I solved the problem, the error was because of the format of the entity that i was trying to pass in the response, so i created a simplified DTO and it worked, thanks again for the solution mate!